# Get selected Dropdown value - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown populated with values I get from the database.
I need to perform some queries based on the selected option, but first I need to save the selected value on a new variable.

This is my dropdown:

```
<form name="dashboard_form" action="" id="dashboard_form" method="post">
    <tr>
     <td><?php _e('Select City')?>:</td>
     <td>
        <select class="selected_city" name="selected_city" style="margin: 20px;width:300px;" required>
        <?php
          foreach ( $all_cities as $city ) 
           {
            echo '<option value='.$city->ID.'>'.$city->name.'</option>';
           }
         ?>
        </select>
        </td>
     </tr>
</form>
```

*$all_cities is an array with all the cities.

My jQuery:

```
<script>
            jQuery("#dashboard_form").validate({
                ignore:'',
                rules: {
                    'selected_city': {
                     required: true
                }},
                messages: {
                    'selected_city': "Please Select a City",
                },
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    jQuery(element).closest('tr').next().find('.error_label').html(error);
                }
            });
</script>
```

How can I save on a $new_variable my selected value from the dropdown?

EDIT 1:

I added the following to

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selected_city;

    $('.selected_city').change(function() {
        selected_city = $(this).val();
        alert(selected_city);
    });
});
```

The alert(selected_city) prints the correct city, how can I use this selected_city on the PHP?

EDIT2:
The problem is the dropdown is not submitting anything, so I created a Button to force it to Submit:

```
 <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Send Now')?>" name="send_now_button" id="send_now_button" class="button button-primary">
```

Then:

```
if(isset($_POST['send_now_button'])){
        if(isset($_POST['selected_city'])) { $selected_city = $_POST['selected_city']; } else {$selected_city = 'Lisboa';  } }
```

Now when I echo $selected_cities_id; it gives the correct value!

Comment: Isn't it in `$_POST['selected_city']`?

Comment: I have this: if(isset($_POST['selected_city'])) { $selected_city = $_POST['selected_city']; } else {$selected_city = '*';  } But it's always *

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show? Are you waiting until the form is submitted before you do this?

Comment: var_dump_($_POST) returns: array(0) { }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. `<tr>` can't be the child of `<form>`, it has to be the child or `<table>`, `<tbody>`, `<thead>`, or `<tfoot>`. This could be preventing the `<select>` from being treated as part of the form, so nothing is being submitted.

You need to put the form around the entire table.

```
<form name="dashboard_form" action="" id="dashboard_form" method="post">
    <table>
        ...
        <tr>
            <td><?php _e('Select City')?>:</td>
            <td>
                <select class="selected_city" name="selected_city" style="margin: 20px;width:300px;" required>
                <?php
                foreach ( $all_cities as $city ) 
                {
                    echo '<option value='.$city->ID.'>'.$city->name.'</option>';
                }
                ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I've added <table> but there is no change

Comment: And you're really sure that you're only checking the value of `$_POST` after the form has been submitted? It will be empty when the page is first loaded, but should be filled in with all the form fields when you submit it.

Comment: I guess the form was NOT being submitted. I created a button to "force" submit and it works now. I'll update

Comment: Thank you @Barmar, you were right, the $_POST was empty.

Comment: If you want to submit the form when the user selects something from the menu, you can put `this.form.submit()` in the `.change()` function.